# Playwright: pause execution whenever 'loading' element is present (add actionability check)

Tags: javascript, playwright

I'm testing a vendor's web application, so I don't have access to the code. This application shows a loading bar at various times, including between page loads, but sometimes even after selecting menu options or checking boxes.

I've found that performing actions while this loading bar is present can cause unexpected problems. I've been waiting for the loading bar to disappear every action that triggers loading, but my test script is quickly filling up with `waitForLoadingBar` functions.

This is the function:

```
const waitForLoadingBar = async (page, expect) => {
  await expect(page.locator('#loading-bar')).toHaveCount(0, {timeout: 30000});
};
```

Can I set this function to run globally after every action? Is it possible to add a custom actionability check, or modify the `click()` and `check()` functions to wait for this element to disappear?

Answer (score 0):

**Prior to playwright 1.42:**

You can inject mutation observer(in the setup part of the given test isolation instance) and listen to poll the page mutations, catch the event and wait for element to be hidden.

I have next helper for this purposes:

```
async observeElementAddedToDomAndWaitToBeDetached(css: string, locator: Locator, { timeout = 5000 } = {}) {
        const checkMessage = await this.observeCssAddedToDomAndFireConsoleMessage(css);
        this.page.on('console', async message => {
            if (message.text() === checkMessage) {
                try {
                    await locator.waitFor({ state: 'hidden', timeout: timeout });
                    await this.debounceDom(50, 300);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(`"${css}" loader hasn't been detached from DOM in ${timeout}ms`); //don't fail test if loader has residues in DOM
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private async observeCssAddedToDomAndFireConsoleMessage(css: string): Promise<string> {
        const checkMessage = `${css} has been added to the DOM`;
        await this.page.evaluate(
            ({ css, checkMessage }) => {
                const observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
                    document.querySelector(css) && console.log(checkMessage);
                });
                // Start observing the document for changes
                observer.observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });
                return null;
            },
            {
                css,
                checkMessage,
            }
        );
        return checkMessage;
    }
```

**observeCssAddedToDomAndFireConsoleMessage** - evaluates the mutation observer on the page in test that will fire specific console message when the dom element with the given css selector will be detected

**observeElementAddedToDomAndWaitToBeDetached** - function with event listener that listens console for this specific message and, if detected, waits for the given loader(by css) to be hidden

Then it can be used in some global base fixture(like **login** or **setup**, you name it, that is executed before each test) to inject event listeners for each loader that exist in the application

```
// mutation observer and listener to catch loader popups(.wait-message) and wait for them to be detached
            const observableLoadersCss = ['.wait-message', '.p-blue-loader', '[class*=loaderWrap]'];
            for (const css of observableLoadersCss) {
                await basicHelper.observeElementAddedToDomAndWaitToBeDetached(css, page.locator(css), {
                    timeout: 15000,
                });
            }
```

**After playwright 1.42 introduced**

There is new experimental feature [addLocatorHandler](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-add-locator-handler) that may make things even more simple
As far as I can see now this could be just a one-liner solution contrary to mutation-observer approach I've used before